# Error with End.x1Down and End.x1Up. Last Cell in Range Declaration Microsoft VBA - Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

(EDITED, SEE BELOW FOR PREVIOUS MESSAGE)
Based on the linked posts and suggestion comments, I changed my code to include this line (I've tried with x1Up and x1Down)

```html
Dim row As Integer
row = Worksheets("Quickbooks").Range("H2").End(x1Down).row
Worksheets("Quickbooks").Range(Worksheets("Quickbooks").Cells(2, "J"), Worksheets("Quickbooks").Cells(row, "J")).Value = 1
```

I'm getting an "Application-defined or object-defined error" now, and I'm not sure what is causing it. Do you have any ideas?

------PREVIOUS POST------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I'm new to VBA and having a hard time with implementing the last cell/row/column functions in code. In this line of code I'm trying to delineate a range with one of these functions. I want the range to go from cell J2 to cell Jend. J is filled with just the value "1" and Jend is determined by column H. When column H has no more values, J should stop too. I get errors when I try this and other variations of it. How would you recommend fixing it/writing it? And, maybe more generally, any tips or rules of thumb for using these last cell functions in range declarations? Thank you!

```
Worksheets("Quickbooks").Range(Cells(2, "J"), Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Select) = 1
```

Comment: `Worksheets("Quickbooks").Range(Worksheets("Quickbooks").Cells(2, "J"), Worksheets("Quickbooks").Cells(Worksheets("Quickbooks").Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)).Value = 1`

Comment: Or `With Worksheets("Quickbooks")`, `.Range(.Cells(2, "J"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)).Value = 1`, `End With`.

Comment: @BigBen when I use your first suggestion, columns H, I, and J are set to 1, instead of just J...any idea why this might be? It's the only line of code that changes. When I remove it, to shows me my normal outputs...

Comment: @BigBen I get the same issue when I try the With End With

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't actually read the body of your question. Use `With Worksheets("Quickbooks")`, `Dim lastRow As Long`, `lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row`, `.Range("J2:J" & lastRow).Value = 1`, `End With`.

Comment: @BigBen how would you do this without the with/end with statement? Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with using `With`? It's a lot easier.

Comment: I tried this to make a different range flexible and it worked: Dim lrowTC As Long
lrowTC = Worksheets("TC Site Report").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Set TCSiteReport = Worksheets("TC Site Report").Range("B2:B" & lrowTC). But then when I did this, Dim LrowIQ As Long
LrowIQ = Worksheets("QuickCalcs").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(x1Up).row
Set itemQuickDescrip = Worksheets("Quickbooks").Range("I2:I" & LrowIQ) I get an application defined or object defined error. I'm not sure why as they seem to be the same thing.

Comment: `xlUp` - the letter `l` as in `lambda`.